# Как привести к интерфейсу коллекцию в MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Столкнулся с проблемой, что нельзя привести к одному интерфейсу данные.
К примеру, у нас есть какой-то интерфейс:

```
public interface IProduct{}
```

От него наследуются классы:

```
public class ProductA : IProduct{}

public class ProductA : IProduct{}
```

Так же у нас есть DataContext:

```
public class DataContext
{
    private MongoClient _client;
    private IMongoDatabase _context;

    public DataContext()
    {
    
        _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        
        _context = _client.GetDatabase("Product");

        Product = _context.GetCollection<IProduct>("Products");
   

        
    }


    public IMongoCollection<IProduct> Product{ get; set; }
```

Если я сделаю ProductA, а потом попробую взаимодействовать с ним:

```
DataContext _context = new DataContext();
 _context.SetSetting.InsertOne(new ProductA);
```

Собственно, у меня этот пример не будет работать, ибо MongoDb, как я понял, не умеет работать с интерфейсами. Как это можно устранить на данном примере?

Comment: Явное приведение к типу IProduct, если конечно проблема в этом. .InsertOne((IProduct)new ProductA()). Какая конкретно ошибка?

Comment: @Cryodd Type ProductA is not configured as an allowed type for this instance of ObjectSerializer.